# 'Locking' FullCalendar on one week

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I'm more of a backend person, so forgive me for my lack of knowledge regarding Javascript.

The calendar view I am going for is 'timeGridWeek', but with no dates, nor ability to flip forward or backward as it is not needed.

Essentially, the calendar enables users to create recurring rules for one type of event in my application. These rules are day-specific, but persist in their configuration permeanently, until a user changes them. Therefore, only a small portion of FullCalendar functionality is needed. One 'week', in grid format.

Is this possible out of the box for FullCalendar? Or will it take javascript wizardy that I'll have to learn?

If my question is not clear, I am happy to clarify, this has me stuck.

Thank you!